# Dirty Checking for an object?

Tags: .net

Consider the following object:

```
Public Class Foo
   dim m_SomePropertyInFoo as string

    public property SomePropertyInFoo as string
    get
        return m_SomePropertyInFoo
    end get
    set(value as string)
        m_SomePropertyInFoo = value
    end set
end Class
```

I want to determine when `SomePropertyInFoo` has a new value which would qualify the instance of `Foo` as dirty.  Here is the catch:  I don't want to have to call some function in each setter because I don't want the devs to have to implement code each time(because they could make a mistake and miss a property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the catch: I don't want to have to call some function in each setter because I don't want the devs to have to implement code each time(because they could make a mistake and miss a property).

There are two options I could see.

If your type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you could subscribe to the object's `PropertyChanged` event and use this to track for changes.

Otherwise, if you want to implement this *with no changes to the code of the properties*, external change tracking would be required.  You could make a method that used Reflection (or potentially [PropertyDescriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx)) to grab the value of each property, and later, compare it to the current values to determine if that object is "dirty".  This is not an inexpensive operation, however.

Another, potentially more elegant, option would be to use [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to add the code to each property automatically at compile time.  [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) could be made to handle this fairly easily, for example.

Comment: we came up with the second suggestion of yours as an option.  The debate we are having is having to duplicate memory.  But good to know that we've been thinking along those lines.

Comment: @Achilles: It's ugly - but it works.  If you want to avoid putting code in the properties, you pretty much HAVE to copy memory...

Answer (score 2):

One option is using a runtime proxy like Castle DynamicProxy

http://www.castleproject.org/services/index.html

Here is a blog post that shows "Tracking dirtiness with DynamicProxy"

http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/8

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options if you do not want to re-code each property.

1. Consider using a framework that can be used to weave code into you class automatically that can implement change tracking e.g. [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/data).
2. Serialize the instance when you first retrieve it, serialize it at the point you save it and do a compare of the bytes.

1 is preferable, whereas 2 is cheap and nasty perhaps.

Comment: We've thought about number 2 definitely.  I'm scared of having to duplicate the memory, but to save dev mistakes it may make sense.

Comment: @Achilles It is a rather brute force approach and could lead to unexpected memory problems e.g. unexpected huge\heavy object graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Set m_SomePropertyInFoo to null (Nothing in VB) initially. Then, when you want to check whether a value has been set, check whether it's null.

You'll have to adjust the setter to return String.Empty if the value is null, otherwise you'll have to handle NullReference exceptions in the next layer up, which is no fun. My VB is a little rusty, but here goes:

```
dim m_SomePropertyInFoo as string = Nothing

public property SomePropertyInFoo as string
    get
        If m_SomePropertyInFoo Is Nothing Then
            return string.Empty
        Else
            return m_SomePropertyInFoo
        End If
    end get
    set(value as string)
        m_SomePropertyInFoo = value
    end set
```

Comment: Say the property is an integer. Say the original value is 4. Code changes the value to 0. In VB terms, *Nothing for an integer is also 0*. Is 0 dirty or not dirty?

Comment: Use Nullable types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx. 0 != Nothing here. I didn't bother to specify that with this example because string is inherently nullable.

Comment: This also requires adding code to the property definition, which the OP specifically wanted to avoid...

Comment: Nullable types are good. But even still, what if the changed value *is* null. To the point, I'm working on the assumption that initial values might not be *default* values, such as if you have a object representing pre-existing data that can be mutated and resaved. Magic values and even nullables might not give you the behavior you desire.

Comment: Well, he said the setter specifically, but yes.

Comment: @Anthony - good point about the changed value. It's basically this or external change tracking (see above). The requirement not to modify the setter is the killer.

Comment: @Chris yeah I know that's the challenge not being able to modify the setter.