# Fully automatic dirty flag (for all members of a class) in C#

Tags: c#, class

We want to keep track of all the changes made in a class so we can later update only the delta to our database, and I was wondering what's the best way to do it.

Our only constraint is that need to keep track of objects only **after** they have been loaded and populated from the database, and I want to keep the data objects as simple as possible (and we'd rather put more stress on the API layer, rather than on our database layer).

In a previous project, we've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (of sorts), but this required to manually track every property in our class and added a lot of manual development overhead, and it greatly inflated our data objects.

I was thinking of implementing a fully automatic solution, which all of our objects can inherit from, and once we tell the object to "begin tracking changes", it will perform a deep copy of the object using reflection - to be later compared when we "end tracking changes", which should output only the deltas in the object.

--

So I was hoping to get some thoughts on my idea, or if anyone can think of a better solution.

Comment: if you use Fody.PropertyChanged then very little additional code is needed for INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @thumbmunkeys that is very cool, did not know this existed - I'll look into it, thanks

Link for anyone else who's interested: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: Not sure of the complexity of your objects, but I have used the datatable class for doing something similar, using the GetChanges method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: it seems fody directly supports an `IsChanged` flag which is basically a `IsDirty` flag: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Implementing-An-IsChanged-Flag

Comment: Check a project I've recently published on GitHub: TrackerDog. Full documentation here: http://mfidemraizer.github.io/trackerdog and Git repository here: https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog

Comment: Hey @MatíasFidemraizer, thanks for the share that was exactly what I was looking for! Are you aware of any high scale usage in production of your project?

Comment: @Ron What do you mean? Do you mean what happens with performance? Well, I doubt that it could be a bottleneck, since the approach is very simple (yet complex to implement), but the callstack isn't too long

Comment: @Ron For now, since I released it few weeks ago, I don't know if someone is using it in production. Well, some friend is using it at work, and obviously, I've implemented it to use it in some project I'm also developing at work. It's up to us to be able to explain good stories about TrackerDog :)

Comment: @Ron At least there're basic tests to check how it works and that won't fail in common scenarios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dirty Checking for an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738533/dirty-checking-for-an-object)